# Is there any way to bind Plain text using ng-bind-html

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using `ng-bind-html` with Paragraph tag. e.g

```
<p ng-bind-html="Message"></p>
```

It is working as expected when I get html in Message but when It is Plain text it is not rendering the Message.  Can someone explain the reason?  Message may contain Html or may not. Any help will be appreciable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use trustAsHtml filter without using further module,

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("exApp",["ngSanitize"]);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $sce){
$scope.message = $sce.trustAsHtml('Hello this is text <a href="#">Kristoff</a> ' +
     'this is my domain <a href="http://www.website.com/">www.website.com</a>');
$scope.messageplain = $sce.trustAsHtml("Hellow");
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="exApp">
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
<span ng-bind-html="message"></span>
 
<span ng-bind-html="messageplain"></span>
 
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `ngSanitize` module. [Here is the plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/tOKjFyIChFrRHQHk45hN?p=preview) , try [removing](https://plnkr.co/edit/nkCsl0KiQW0CgOG1GnI5?p=preview) the module injection and see the behavior

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p ng-bind-html="myText"></p>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myText = "My name is: John Doe";
});
</script>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example includes the "angular-sanitize.js",
which has functions for removing potentially dangerous tokens from the HTML.</p>

</body>
</html>
```